# Solarized Dark PuTTY isn't displaying correctly

Tags: putty, colors, color-theme, solarized

If I do `ls` on PuTTY with no color settings changed, it changes the font color of directories to make everything easier to read.

I'm trying to change the colors to the solarized-dark theme, since PuTTY's default colors are horrendous. The last time I did this, I had no problem (downloaded .reg file, loaded the session, etc - just followed exact instructions github).

This time, however, doing this changes the colors properly... but now `ls` just lists everything in the same off-white font color. (I've also tried going through `Window -> Colours -> Select color to adjust:` and manually entering every RGB value... but the same problem occurs)

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I've also tried changing `Connection -> Data -> Terminal Type-string` from xterm to xterm-256color, and `Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode` is enabled

Is there something I'm missing? How can I make it display everything properly again?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this fixed it for me:

```
Settings -> Window -> Colours -> Indicate bolded text by changing: (X) The font
```

Select `The Font`. It's defaulted to `The colour` I believe, and that didn't work for me.